# Jenkins Xcode build works but aichive failed with Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, jenkins, build, codesign

error is:
unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

I can run build shell success in my own mac, but when I use it by Jenkins and use my mac as a node of Jenkins, it has the above mistakes. The root Jenkins is build on linux.

I have tried many method, but it doesn't work, for example:

cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

xattr -dr com.apple.FinderInfo *

cd project

find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec xattr -c {} \;

xattr -rc project

Answer (score 3):

I solved this question by unlocking my keychain before codesign:

security -v unlock-keychain -p password ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain

Comment: Still i'm getting codesign alert we i call xcodebuild -project ZizeraApp.xcodeproj -configuration Release build -scheme ZizeraApp archive PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER="$BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="$PROFILE_NAME" CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS='' CODE_SIGN_STYLE='Manual' -archivePath ZizeraApp.xcarchive